# Find the $\int \frac{(1-y^2)}{(1+y^2)}dy$

Tags: integration

$\int \frac{(1-y^2)}{(1+y^2)}dy$ first I tried to divide then I got 1-$\frac{2y^2}{1+y^2}$ and i still can't integrate it.

Comment: Polynomial division or equivalently $\frac{1-y^2}{1+y^2}=\frac{2-(1+y^2)}{1+y^2}=\frac{2}{1+y^2}-1$.

Answer (score 5):

HINT:try with       $$1-y^2=2-(1+y^2)$$

Comment: wait how will i think of that?

Comment: The fraction is top-heavy so you need to do long division, or the eqivalent, first

Comment: @Kashka, Write $$1-y^2=A+B(1+y^2)$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$ \int \frac{1-y^2}{1+y^2}dy = \int \frac{1}{1+y^2}dy-\int \frac{y^2}{1+y^2}dy$$

Note (using long division or otherwise): $$\int \frac{y^2}{1+y^2}dy = \int dy -\int \frac{1}{1+y^2}dy$$

Therefore:$$  \int \frac{1-y^2}{1+y^2}dy = 2\int\frac{1}{1+y^2}dy -\int dy$$

The solution should be straight forward from here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y = \tan \theta \Rightarrow I = \displaystyle \int \dfrac{\cos^2\theta - \sin^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta}d\theta= \displaystyle \int (1-\tan^2 \theta)d\theta = \displaystyle \int (2-\sec^2\theta)d\theta= 2\theta - \tan \theta + C=2\tan^{-1}y-y+C$